# Sum of independent random variables

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

We know that the sum of two independent normal random variables is again a normal random variable. But is the reverse right? If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables satisfying $X+Y$~$N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for some $\mu$ and $\sigma$, can we conclude that both $X$ and $Y$ obey normal distribution? or under some conditions added on $p_X$ and $p_Y$ (the density functions of $X$ and $Y$)?

Comment: what if $X=constant$ ?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: People often consider a constant to be $N(\mu,0)$.

Comment: Which people???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, and the same holds for Poisson, and for mixtures of Gauss and Poisson.
All these are special cases of the general question: if $X_j$ are independent
and we know the distribution of their sum, what can be said about the distributions of the $X_j$. This general question is addressed in the book
Linnik, Ostrovskii, Decomposition of random variables and vectors, AMS 1977
(translation from the Russian).

Answer (score 19):

Yes, they are normally distributed.  This is the [Lévy-Cramér theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/L%C3%A9vy-Cram%C3%A9r_theorem).